# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{i=1}^n Fib(n-i).i^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

$S(n,k) = \sum_{i=1}^n Fib(n-i).i^k$

$\implies\ S(n,k) = Fib(n-1)(1)^k + Fib(n-2)(2)^k + Fib(n-3).(3)^k +... + Fib(0)n^k$

$Fib(i)$ is the $i_{th}$ Fibonacci term with $Fib(0)=0$ and $Fib(1)=1$

**My thoughts ,**

For k=0, its simply sum of fibonacci http://oeis.org/A000071

$S(n,0) = F(n+1)-1$

For k=1,

$S(n,1) =  Fib(n-1)1 + Fib(n-2)2 + Fib(n-3)3 +... + Fib(0)n$

from oeis we get the following series http://oeis.org/A001924
$S(n,1)         = Fib(n+4) - (n+3)$

For k=2,
http://oeis.org/A053808
$S(n,2)         = Fib(n+6) - (n^2 + 4n + 8)$

For k=3,
http://oeis.org/A213570
$S(n,3)         = Fib(n+9) + Lucas(n+8) - (n^3 + 9n^2 + 39n + 81)$

For $k\ge 4$ oeis can no longer help.

From the above four cases the intuition I get is, the result should be something like $c.Fib(n) - some\ K\ degree\ polynomial$

If so then it indeed has a closed form (as Fibonacci and Lucas have closed forms).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139194/discussion-on-question-by-layla-bailey-find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-i1n).